# консольный ввод в rust

Tags: консоль, input, rust

Как мне получить консольный ввод в rust

Я могу привети пример программы на других языках
python:

```
a = input("enter num: ")
print("your num is "+a)
```

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
string a;
cout << "enter num: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "your num is " << a << endl;
}
```

Я нвшел ответ:

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::io;

fn read_string(comment:&str) -> String {
    print!("{}", comment);
    io::stdout().flush();

    let mut string: String = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut string)
        .ok()
        .expect("Error read line!");

    return string;
}
```

Comment: Элементарно хД `io::stdin().lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap()`

Comment: Я знаком с этим способом но я хочу что бы перед тем как запрашивать данные в 
эту же строку выводилось "enter num: "

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел ответ

```
    use std::io::Write;
    use std::io;
    
    fn read_string(comment:&str) -> String {
        print!("enter num: ");
        io::stdout().flush();
    
        let mut string: String = String::new();
    
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut string)
            .ok()
            .expect("Error read line!");
        print!("your num is {}\n", num)
        return string;
    }
```